# only one instance of resultSet is allowed while connecting SQL SEVER using DSN

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, dsn

i am  getting bellow error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt
```

my code

```
private static final String DRIVER = "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:odbc:sql2008";
private String[] entity = {"TABLE","VIEW"};
private ResultSet tables,columns,resultSet;

public void getData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection  connection=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
    DatabaseMetaData data = connection.getMetaData();
     resultSet =  data.getCatalogs();

     while (resultSet.next()) {
         String dbName = resultSet.getString("TABLE_CAT");
        if(dbName.toString().equals("db")){
            tables=data.getTables(dbName, "%", "%", entity);
            while (tables.next()) {
                           System.out.println(tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

URL is DSN connection(connction using dsn name ) and 
I am getting this error while trying to  fetch tables which is again ResultSet 
but its work fine in DSN-less  connection that is directly (using address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over two resultsets at the same time:

1. `while (resultSet.next()) {`
2. `while (tables.next()) {`

According to the error message, this is not allowed.

You could fix it by putting the result of the first iteration in a `List<String> databaseNames` and then iterating over that list to list the tables.

Alternatively, if you're using SQL Server 2005, you might want to try enabling a feature in SQL Server called "[Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)".